# Leaflet.js custom coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, web-mapping, mapping

**Background**:
Display topographic plans of a specific size (1500 meters x 1500 meters). The source images of tiles can be of different sizes and resolutions. It is required to display on the plan some objects tied to their own proprietary coordinate system.

**Problem**:
Display the map tiles turned out. How can I attach my own coordinate system to an existing map?
I tried several solutions (for example, CRS.Simple, rastercoords), but, unfortunately, nothing came of it for various reasons: the tile display was spoiled, or it was not possible to bind proprietary coordinates.

```js
const IMAGE_SIZES = [img_width, img_height];
const MAX_ZOOM = 1;
const MIN_ZOOM = 5;
const INITIAL_ZOOM = 3;

let map = map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    minZoom: MIN_ZOOM,
    maxZoom: MAX_ZOOM,

});
map.setView([0, 0], INITIAL_ZOOM);

L.tileLayer('example.com/plan_id/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  noWrap: true
}).addTo(map)
```

Maybe 
I did something wrong, please tell me how I can do this. Below is an example of a grid
[image]

For example, if I have a scanned plan (in the image, the area is highlighted in yellow). It is cut into tiles, it is already displayed with zooming with loading tiles. How can I now snap to the image a coordinate grid similar to the one in the picture?

Comment: One of the basic policies of this site requires that coding questions should include relevant existing code of what has been tried so far. Please edit your question and add relevant code, otherwise question is most likely to be closed as not being conformant to the site policy.

Comment: @TomazicM Thank you for your comment. I tried to fix it as I could. Unfortunately, not all the code was saved, since I tried a lot of things ha these days

Comment: What do you get from your code above and how does it differ from what you are trying to achieve? What is `L.RasterCoords`?

Comment: @TomazicM , sorry for not spelling out the issue in detail.
[Rastercoords](https://github.com/commenthol/leaflet-rastercoords) - this is the plugin i tried to use to solve the problem
This code does not work for me, since the coordinates on the edges of the map do not correspond to those that I need (the north-eastern part of the map has coordinates, for example, 0, 0 instead of 3278.000, 4537.400, which I need). Maybe I'm missing something, but I can’t achieve the desired effect

Comment: If you successfuly displayed tiles without a grid, please include in your question whole JS code that worked OK.

Comment: With the exception of the starting position of the display, all the code that was working for me is presented. A code snippet with a starting position has been added to the listing. I tried to change the starting values, but this did not work. Also tried not to use the rastercoords plugin